# Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s): Postgres server wal_level property must be "logical" but is: replica You ca

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, change-data-capture

I am trying to start Kafka Connect service with Debezium Postgres Connector with this command:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-debezium-postgres.properties
```

After running the command I'm getting this error:

```
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,177] ERROR Postgres server wal_level property must be "logical" but is: replica (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector:101)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,293] INFO Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:965)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,305] INFO AbstractConfig values: 
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:376)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,561] ERROR Failed to create job for config/connect-debezium-postgres.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,576] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):        
Postgres server wal_level property must be "logical" but is: replica
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:114)    
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
Postgres server wal_level property must be "logical" but is: replica
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:691)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:207)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.lambda$null$0(StandaloneHerder.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)    
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)    
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,611] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:67)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,612] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:311)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,673] INFO Stopped http_8083@26be6ca7{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:381)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,674] INFO node0 Stopped scavenging (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:149)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,710] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:328)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,711] INFO Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:106)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,733] INFO Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:199)  
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,734] INFO Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:66)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,737] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:659)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,739] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:663)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,740] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:669)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,741] INFO App info kafka.connect for 10.0.2.15:8083 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,752] INFO Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:220)   
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,819] INFO Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:124)
[2022-02-22 20:36:06,820] INFO Kafka Connect stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:72)
```

The thing is I have already updated wal_level to 'logical' on postgresql.conf and restart to take effect with this command:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_reload_conf();
 pg_reload_conf 
----------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Try using the 'pg_ctl reload' command but facing an issue:

```
postgres=# pg_ctl reload;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_ctl"
LINE 1: pg_ctl reload;
        ^
```

Is this the correct way to reload the Postgres server after making changes to 'postgresql.conf' file? Is there any other way to resolve this error?

Comment: Changing wal_level requires a full restart not just a reload.

Comment: I try to restart the Postgres using 'sudo systemctl restart postgresql-14' but unfortunately right after running the command, Postgres status is failed. Is there any way I can restart Postgres?

Comment: look in the log file to see why it failed.

Comment: `pg_ctl` is a shell command, not a SQL function. Exit the SQL prompt for it.

Comment: After stop and start the Postgres service. The Postgres service failed to start since there is an error at postgresql.conf that is: 'configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/14/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors; unaffected changes were applied received fast shutdown request     
2022-02-23 01:59:08.939 +08 [13458] LOG:  aborting any active transactions   
2022-02-23 01:59:09.142 +08 [13458] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 13467) exited with exit code 1'